# The events A,B,C,D are independent such that $P(A)=P(B)=\frac12$, $P(C)=P(D)=\frac34$. Calculate $P((A\cup B)\setminus(C\cup D))$

Tags: probability

The events A,B,C,D are independent such that $P(A)=P(B)=\frac12$, $P(C)=P(D)=\frac34$. Calculate $P(A\setminus (B\cup C))$ and $P((A\cup B)\setminus(C\cup D))$

---

We have $P(A\setminus(B\cup C))=P(A)-P(A\cap (B\cup C))$

and $(B\cup C)\cup (B\cup C)^c= \Omega$, so $A\cap ((B\cup C)\cup (B\cup C)^c)= (A\cap (B\cup C))\cup (A\cap (B\cup C)^c)$. These two sets are disjont so we have:

$P(A)=P(A\cap (B\cup C)) + P(A\cap (B\cup C)^c)$

$\Rightarrow P(A\setminus(B\cup C))= P(A\cap (B\cup C)^c)=${De Morgan} $=P(A\cap B^c \cap C^c)=$ {independence}$=P(A)P(B^c)P(C^c)=\frac1{16}$

It is correct? and any hints how to do the second one, i don't see what can i use there.

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary work in the middle talking about $P(A)-P(A\cap (B\cup C))$.  You should have been able to start right at $\Pr(A\setminus (B\cup C))$ and go straight to the end from there.

Comment: What is the operation $X / Y$ on sets?

Comment: Good point @VIVID.  I assume this is a typo and setminus is intended given the later work shown.  The slash for setminus goes in the other direction @ frugo.

Comment: As for $\Pr((A\cup B)\setminus (C\cup D))$ continue as $\Pr((A\cup B)\cap C^c\cap D^c)=\Pr((A\cap C^c\cap D^c)\cup (B\cap C^c\cap D^c))$ and continue via inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Make sure you're using `\setminus` instead of `/` for set differences.

Comment: Right i've changed it. Anyway thanks